# Solrj backup using java code

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I want to write a java client based on Solrj which pulls the entire core data to a file from a remote Solr server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an open source project that does exactly what you want try to do.

https://github.com/freedev/solr-import-export-json